# SonarQube - how to run the code analysis again for a project after creating that project

Tags: sonarqube, code-analysis

I have created a project and run the code analysis. Later I did some changes in rules and tried to run the code analysis again. But in the UI of http://localhost:9000/projects, I can't find any menu or button to show the instructions of running code analysis. Can anyone help?

---

Update on 25/02/2020

For example, I am using SonarQube for a .NET (C#) project. When I do the code analysis, as SonarQube suggested, I copied the 3 command below into command line.

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"" /d:sonar.host.url=“http://localhost:9000” /d:sonar.login=""

MsBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

SonarScanner.MSBuild.exe end /d:sonar.login=""

If SonarQube can show these commands in UI of http://localhost:9000/dashboard?id=, that will be great. Otherwise, it’s hard to remember these command and the only way to run the code analysis again is to create a new project in SonarQube UI. For now, I copied these 3 commands into a .bat file after creating a project. And every time run this .bat file again after some changes in project configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two important components in the ecosystem:

- SonarQube:

  - serves plugins and project configurations
  - consumes and displays analysis results
- SonarScanner

  - consumes plugins and project configurations
  - performs analysis and publish the results

When you change anything in the project configuration, you have to perform a new analysis to see the results. It means you have to:

> run the code analysis

Comment: mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=<abc_xyz> -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000  -Dsonar.login=<generated-login-guid>

Answer (score 1):

Run the code analysis again the way you did before.

Comment: You mean creating a new project?

Comment: No, run the rpject withthe same project key

mvn sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=my-projecy-key-here \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000 \

or 

in the project source code root create a property file and run sonar scan

sonar.projectKey=my-project-key-here

Answer (score 1):

maybe all he wants is a simple url

```
http://localhost:9000/tutorials?id=yourproject
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: No such page is available on SonarQube local instances as of the time of writing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the following command -

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.host.url=$HOST_URL
```

You can also provide other parameters such as login, password, project key by adding them as a system property. For example to add login password add the following -

```
-Dsonar.login=$USERNAME -Dsonar.password=$PASSWORD
```

This will run the analysis and once completed it will be available on your sonarqube dashboard.